# Create dynamic graphene arguments class

Tags: django, factory-pattern, graphene-python, graphene-django

Just started using graphene for my backend, I have three types of users, they all have username, email and user_type as required, but the rest are optional.

Instead of of creating 3 mutation classes, I'm trying to implement just one generic `CreateUser Class`

My current implementation is:

```
    class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):

        user = graphene.Field(UserType)

        class Arguments:
            # user = graphene.ID()
            email = graphene.String(required=True)
            password = graphene.String(required=True)
            user_type = graphene.String(required=True)
            first_name = graphene.String()
            last_name = graphene.String()
            street_address = graphene.String()
            city = graphene.String()
            state = graphene.String()
            zip_code = graphene.Int()
            date = graphene.Date()
            ... #so on

        def mutate(self, info, email, password, user_type, **kwargs):
            user = CustomUser.objects.create(
                username=email,
                email=email,
                user_type=user_type,
                password=password,
            )

            ... # code where I use kwargs

            return CreateUser(user=user)
```

`QUESTION:` Is there a way to create the `class Arguments:` dynamically at runtime?

Comment: It seems like there are some important details that you've left out of your question.  Are there multiple Django models for each of your user types?

Comment: Yes three different models

Answer (score 1):

Say you have three user models called `UserModel1`, `UserModel2`, and `UserModel3`.

If your different user models have any different fields that you want to allow the mutation to create, you'll need design your list of input arguments to include all of these fields, as optional fields, i.e.

```
    class Arguments:
        email = graphene.String(required=True)  # common required field
        password = graphene.String(required=True)  # common required field
        user_type = graphene.String(required=True)  # required to switch fields
        ...
        user_model1_field = graphene.String()  # some field that's only used in `UserModel1` that must be optional
```

Similarly, for the output type, you could decide if your output type contains all fields for all user models, or just fields that are common between the three different models.

Then, in your mutation method, you can switch on user type and provide an output value that consistent with the output type decisions that you made.

```
    def mutate(self, info, email, password, user_type, **kwargs):
        if user_type == "UserModel1":
            # do stuff to create UserModel1 with **kwargs
            user = UserModel1.object.create(
               ... parse kwargs to get UserModel1's fields
            return UserType(... parse kwargs and or users fields to created)
        elif user_type == "UserModel2":
            # similarly create UserModel2 from kwargs
            ...
        elif user_type == "UserModel3":
            ... etc. etc
```

Comment: That's my current setup

Comment: Oh, I see -- you want to dynamically create the arguments .  Maybe you'll need to overload the mutation class to mess with how the arguments work.  For example, see https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/blob/master/graphene/types/mutation.py